# Diseño de BD de Pedidos con Artículos en diferentes tablas

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Estoy diseñando una base de datos para un cliente que prestará servicio de catering, comida y también shishas.

Los pedidos que sus clientes pueden hacer son de comida, de shishas o de catering, pero nunca se mezclan entre ellos, es decir, tu puedes pedir comida pero no shishas en el mismo pedido, es como si fueran tres negocios independientes.

Además, para el catering necesito recoger el personal que será enviado a realizar el servicio.

He pensado que podría crear una tabla `Pedido` en la que almacene el `id`, la `fecha` y el `cliente` que lo solicita.

El problema es que no sé cómo diseñar el resto, si crear una tabla de `comida`, otra de `shisha` y otra de `catering`, en las que almacene cada uno de los elementos del *pedido* en concreto, relacionándola con la tabla `Pedido`

El problema sería que cuando mi cliente me pide que quiere saber cuál es el pedido que más dinero ha costado entre todos (comida, shishas y catering), necesitaría realizar tres consultas diferentes.

Mi pregunta es: ¿puedo diseñar la BD de alguna forma en la que esta consulta se pueda realizar?

Comment: Lo ideal para esto es tener un la tabla pedido, una campo llamado precio total el qual al insertar el pedido se le active un trigger que haga la suma de la comida, shisha y catering asignado a ella. También puedes hacer un trigger que al hacer select de pedido se añada el campo total con la suma de la consulta. Aun así, es depende del sistema de base de datos de que usas como se hace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a responder la pregunta, aunque no encaje del todo en el formato del sitio.

**Sisha, Comida o Catering:**

Puedes crear una tabla de tipoPedidos que definas para comida, sisha o catering.

El pedido tendrá una columna tipoPedido.

**Catering**

Tabla PersonalPedidosCatering que tiene una clave foránea que apunta a un idPedido. Y una clave foránea que apunta a Personal.

**DetallePedido**

Contendrá las lineas correspondientes a los articulos que definan el pedido. Sean unos u otros. Al final no dejan de ser Artículos o productos (como prefieras llamarlos).

Con este simple esquema ya tienes todos los problemas que planteas solucionados.

**Union**

Ahora bien, si decides cualquier otro modelo, y necesitas consultar datos de tres tablas diferentes que no se relacionan entre ellas, pero devuelven datos del mismo tipo. (Cliente que más ha gastado), tienes el operador.